# Trigonometric Ratios Of Multiple Angles

Tags: trigonometry

If $2\tan A=3\tan B$ then prove that $$\tan(A-B)=\frac{\sin2B}{5-\cos 2B}.$$

I found that $\tan A=\frac{3}{2} \tan B$ and after that used the formula of $\tan (A-B)=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}$ but could not reach to the required answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, here is another method: $$RHS=\frac{\sin 2B}{5-\cos 2B}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{2\tan B}{1+\tan^2B}}{5-\frac{1-\tan^2 B}{1+\tan^2A}}$$
$$=\frac{2\tan B}{4+6\tan^2B}$$
$$=\frac{\tan B}{2+3\tan^2B}$$
$$=\frac{(3\tan B)-2\tan B}{2+(3\tan B)\tan B}$$
setting $3\tan B=2\tan A$, 
$$=\frac{2\tan A-2\tan B}{2+2\tan A\tan B}$$
$$=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\tan B}$$
$$=\tan(A-B)=LHS$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\tan\left(A-B\right) = \dfrac{\tan(A)-\tan(B)}{1+\tan(A)\tan(B)} = \dfrac{\tan(B)/2}{1+\dfrac32 \tan^2(B)} = \dfrac{\tan(B)}{2+3\tan^2(B)} = \dfrac{\dfrac{\sin(B)}{\cos(B)}}{2+3 \cdot \dfrac{\sin^2(B)}{\cos^2(B)}}$$
Hence, we have
$$\tan\left(A-B\right) = \dfrac{\sin(B)\cos(B)}{2\cos^2(B)+3\sin^2(B)} = \dfrac{\sin(2B)}{4+2\sin^2(B)} = \dfrac{\sin(2B)}{5-\cos(2B)}$$
where we made use of $\sin(2B) = 2\sin(B) \cos(B)$, $\cos(2B) = 1-2\sin^2(B)$.